# How to fetch expiry date of ios certificates programmatically

Tags: ios

I want to fetch expiry date of certificate with which my ipa is signed. I need that expiry date to be displayed in application. I am able to fetch provisioning profile expiry date but not of certificate.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21612798/3901620

Comment: @KKRocks this shows how to fetch provisioning profile details not the certificate details

Comment: Can you tell please did you solve this?