# embedded.mobileprovision missing on release builds

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store

I noticed that `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "embedded", ofType: "mobileprovision")` returns nil on release builds but I still able to find this file manually in my binary and with debug configuration.
Does Apple cut this file before release to AppStore/TestFlight?

Comment: may be this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21612798/307547

Comment: It works fine while there is a debug build, unfortunately it doesn't work when the build is made for the AppStore.